# Do stores at tourist-heavy sites in Nepal accept USD?

Tags: money, exchange, trekking, nepal

I will be going to Nepal for [mountain trekking](http://www.himalayanst.com/everest-trekking.html), I want to bring USD simply because it is very hard for me to get Nepalese Rupee in my home country.

At tourist heavy sites, do most stores accept USD? If no, can I get Nepalese Rupee easily at local currency exchange centers?

Comment: Convenient for what? Are you asking about acceptance by stores and locals? Or are you asking about availability of money exchange places before leaving and/or once you get there?

Comment: I am asking about the acceptance by stores and locals, especially around tourist-heavy trekking mountain sites. I edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spending US dollars outside of a city like Kathmandu or Pokhara will be difficult.  And even within those cities, businesses accepting US$ will be limited in numbers (hotels, plus some restaurants and shops).

As pretty much all access to Nepal is via flights into Kathmandu, why not exchange US dollars for NP rupees upon arrival?  One would think that a few minutes would be available to exchange money even on the tightest tour schedule (afterall the guide would want to make sure you have cash to tip the crew ;-)

Comment: and of course you can get NR rupees from an ATM with your credit card.

Comment: ATM's are very unreliable in Nepal. But you will find small exchange offices almost everywhere. Make sure to convert your US dollars at private exchange offices and not at "official" banks, because they will require a lot of unnecessary paperwork.